# How many items can be placed in an array in WHERE IN?

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

I have a query

```
SELECT [whatever] FROM [somewhere] WHERE [someValue] IN [value1, valeue2, ..., valueN]
```

What is the maximum size for N (from valueN above) in an Oracle 10g database? Could it be as high as 10k or 50k?

Comment: Oracle can use TEMP space (disk) as needed (whos size depends on how your DBAs setup your environment)

Comment: 1,000. However, a better question would be, what is a sensible number of `OR` clauses in a query, and I would suggest the number is a lot lower than 1,000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the 'expression list' version of the [`IN` condition](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions013.htm), which appears to be the case from your question though you're missing the brackets around the list of values,  then you're limited by the [expression list](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions014.htm) itself:

> A comma-delimited list of expressions can contain no more than 1000
>   expressions. A comma-delimited list of sets of expressions can contain
>   any number of sets, but each set can contain no more than 1000
>   expressions.

If you're using the subquery version then there is no limit, other than possibly system resources.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle has a fixed limit of 1000 elements for an IN clause as documented in the manual:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/conditions013.htm#i1050801

> *You can specify up to 1000 expressions in expression_list.*

Answer (score 2):

This [thread](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=908874%20thread) suggests that the limit is 1000. However, I would suggest you don't even go there and instead place your values in a table and turn your query into a subselect. Much neater, more flexible and better performance.

Comment: Is the size of the subquery limited?

Answer (score -1):

That is depends up on the number of rows you have for that particular column. In some cases it may be millions of records you have in table .

Comment: There are tens of millions of entries in that table, but how does this matter?